# Modifying Apache configuration via a Web Interface

Tags: apache-2.2, bash, mod-security

I would like to create a website on my server, which runs Apache2, to allow a user to fill in a form containing a desired subdomain name to be created on the server. For example, a user could go to the site on the server at `example.com`, fill out the form with a desired subdomain 'custom_subdomain', and on the server-side, a script will create the appropriate `Vhost file` in `apache2/sites-available`, a2ensite it,  and restart the apache2 server.

This will effectively create `custom_subdomain.example.com` on the server. What I'm unsure of is how to create a server-side script which can actually perform these actions since they require root level access (both to create a new vhost file and restart the server). I DO NOT want apache2 running as ROOT and lets assume I properly escape the user's desired subdomain entry so that it does not contain malicious code. Also my website will have some form of login security. 
How can I go about writing such a script? My back-end will be written in (Django) Python or Node.js.

The reason I wish to create this interface is that I have some collaborators who should have the ability to create subdomains easily, but who should not have the ability to tinker with any apache configuration manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about not re-inventing the wheel and just use a control panel like ISPConfig. You can disable unwanted features and only allow the subdomaining.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into using a ready-made server control panel.

Comment: For other readers, I also found munin, webmin/virtualmin/cloudmin, and cpanel to be worth looking into. I went with webmin.